# Group actions in a homotopy category

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $M$ be a model category and $G$ a finite group, and equip the category $M^G$ of $G$-objects in $M$ with, say, a projective model structure.  Then there is a canonical functor

$$\mathrm{Ho}(M^G) \to \mathrm{Ho}(M)^G. $$

Surprisingly (to me), if $M$ is additive and the cardinality of $G$ is invertible in $M$, then this functor is fully faithful.

I learned this from [1303.0153](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0153) which says that although it is "certainly well-known, we haven’t been able to find it in the literature".  But surely someone has noticed this or something like it before?  Even an offhand remark without a proof would be a useful reference, even in some special case like chain complexes over $\mathbb{Q}$ or localized spectra.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/sfb343/preprints/pr98032.ps.gz

Comment: @BenWieland hmm, can you explain why?

Comment: Cooke's paper ("Replacing homotopy actions by topological actions", TransAMS)  proves this for M=p-local spaces (e.g., Theorem 2.3).

Comment: @CharlesRezk Thanks!  That's exactly the sort of paper that I felt sure must exist.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @CharlesRezk hmm, although now that I look at it more carefully, his Theorem 2.3 actually shows that the functor in question is essentially surjective, rather than fully faithful!

Comment: @MikeShulman It's not hard: To realize a diagram, just look at maps from $BG$ to the classifying space of the automorphisms of the diagram. I agree it doesn't answer your question as posed.

Answer (score 4):

The spectral sequence I constructed with Niles Johnson was precisely designed to handle questions of this sort (here is a version that is closer to the publication version: [T-algebra SS](http://www.nullplug.org/publications/obstruction-theory.pdf)). A special case of your question is considered in Section 5.1. Our methods require a suitably enriched model category (we focus on simplicial model categories), but it is easy to see that you get a similar spectral sequence for spectral or chain complex enrichments. In such a case the obstructions to the existence and uniqueness of a lift of a given map $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ from $\mathrm{Ho}(M)^G$ to $\mathrm{Ho}(M^G)$ lie in the positive dimensional Borel cohomology of $X$ with coefficients in various shifts of $Y$. Using a tensor and cotensor with spaces, we can write this more precisely: the obstructions are the $t$th cohomology groups of the cosimplicial abelian group $\mathrm{ho}(M^G)_{\downarrow Y}(G^{\bullet+1}\otimes X,Y^{S^t}))$ for $t>0$. Here the source has the simplicial structure coming from a bar construction.

When the order of $G$ acts invertibly on these cohomology groups, the restriction and transfer homomorphisms exhibit these groups as retracts of the corresponding cohomology with the *trivial* group. Of course these groups are trivial in positive degrees so there is a unique lift of each map.

Of course, I am assuming some kind of nice enriched model structure here, so I am not answering your question exactly. On the other hand, in these case I think you can get away with less: You probably just need $Y$ to be a homotopy monoid in $\mathrm{Ho}(M)$ (to get the $E_2$ description as a bunch of abelian groups) and you only need the order of $G$ to act invertibly on this $E_2$ term in positive cohomological degrees.

I apologize that the linked reference is not quite complete. We are in the middle of making revisions for publication. The article will later appear in Advances in Mathematics.

Comment: Thanks!  So in particular, if $M$ is additive, then every object is a homotopy monoid, so the result should apply.  It's interesting that in the special case of actions by a group with invertible order one can prove it without such an involved calculation.

Comment: As often happens, behind a vanishing spectral sequence argument lies a more elementary argument. My more involved method is probably overkill in this case.
Nonetheless, the argument indicates why it is true. For $X,Y\in M^G$ we have a map $$ \mathrm{tr}\colon M(X,Y)\rightarrow M^G(X,Y)$$ given by $f(-)\mapsto \sum_{g\in G} (g\cdot f)(-)=\sum_{g\in G} gf(g^{-1} -)$. I suspect that $\mathrm{tr}$ descends to homotopy categories, perhaps by an argument with right homotopies. If this is the case, then precomposing with the restriction functor gives a self map on mapping sets in $\mathrm{Ho}(M^G)$..

Comment: . whose composite is multiplication by $|G|$ and which factors through $\mathrm{Ho}(M)^G(X,Y)$. From here one can see that $\mathrm{Ho}(M^G)(X,Y)\cong\mathrm{Ho}(M)^G(X,Y)$ when $|G|$ acts invertibly. It appears the non-trivial part is seeing that $\mathrm{tr}$ descends to the homotopy category.